# IOS unrecognized selector on Object Segue

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I'm making an iOS app but I'm trying to send an object to another view controller but it throws me this error

> Blockquote-[UINavigationController setUserObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x156aa330

Here's my code:
loginViewController.m
this is user it's already allocated the object with the values of name, email, and lastname

```
#import "PerfilViewController.h"
#import "User.h"
@interface LogInViewController (){
    User *user;
}
@end
(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"loggedIn"]) {
user.name = self.nameText.text
user.lastname = self.lastNameText.text
        PerfilViewController *pvc = [segue destinationViewController];
        [pvc setUserObject: user];
    }
}
```

In my destination controller I have this its as well allocated on viewDidLoad

```
#import "PerfilViewController.h"
#import "User.h"
@interface PerfilViewController (){
    User *user;
}

@end

@implementation PerfilViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self setViewValues];
    [self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES];
    user = [[User alloc] init];
}

#pragma mark - Segue
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}

-(void)setUserObject:(User *)userToSet{
    user = userToSet;
}
```

Comment: The error tells me that destinationViewController is of type UINavigationController.It seems that you have embedded PerfilViewController instance in UINavigationController.Try to find it in UINavigationController.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the `destinationViewController` is a `UINavigationViewController` so `PerfilViewController` should be its `rootViewController`

```
if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"loggedIn"]) {
    UINavigationController *navigationController = [segue destinationViewController];
    PerfilViewController *pvc = navigationController.rootViewController;
    [pvc setUserObject: user];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess by looking at the code provided is that `[segue destinationViewController]` is not of the class `PerfilViewController`.

you could try checking to see if `pvc` has a method names `setUserObject` and then call that method if `pvc` responds to it. If not, then log out what class `pvc` actually is to help you debug. This should handle that:

```
if ([pvc respondsToSelector:@selector(setUserObject)]) {
    [pvc setUserObject: user];
} else {
    NSLog(@"pvc is of class \"%@\"", [s class]);
}
```